# Select chunked data with row number using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table containing a long text (`varchar(max)`) column and several key columns. I need to load this data into another table, but break the long text into chunks (`varchar(4000)`), so each row in the source table may become multiple rows in the target table.

Is there a way using T-SQL which can do this in one select statement and also provide a `row_number`? Sort of like partition over chunk size, if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive CTE to split the string into 4000 character chunks (as a variation on this comma splitting thread: [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows))

```
;WITH cte(SomeID, RowNum, DataItem, String) AS
(
    SELECT
        SomeID,
        1,
        LEFT(String, 4000),
        case when len(String) > 4000 then
            RIGHT(String, LEN(String) - 4000)
        else
            ''
        end
    FROM myTable
    UNION all

    SELECT
        SomeID,
        RowNum + 1,
        LEFT(String, 4000),
        case when len(String) > 4000 then 
            RIGHT(String, LEN(String) - 4000)
        else
            ''
        end
    FROM cte
    WHERE
        String > ''
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive subquery:

```
with cte as (
      select left(longtext, 4000) as val, 1 as rn,
             stuff(longtext, 1, 4000, '') as rest
      from t
      union all
      select left(rest, 4000), rn + 1,
             stuff(longtext, 1, 4000, '') as rest
      from cte
      where longtext > ''
     )
select *
from cte;
```

You probably want to include other columns as well, but your question doesn't mention them.

Also, if your text is really long (say more than a handful of chunks per row), then this is not going to be the most efficient method.  There are related methods using recursive CTEs to solve this.